# How to connect to mongodb behind nginx with nodejs on same server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have created a droplet via DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 16.04.
I want to deploy my website on the server and I need my nodejs app and mongodb on the server.

I had no problem setting up the nodejs app. I am using pm2 with nginx as reverse proxy and letsencrypt for https.

So, to the problem. I have no idea how to connect to my mongodb server. I have installed mongodb. When I run `sudo systemctl status mongodb` this comes in the output:

```
    mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-06-28 13:12:41 UTC; 2h 4min ago
 Main PID: 13918 (mongod)
    Tasks: 20
   Memory: 61.9M
      CPU: 1min 21.003s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─13918 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Log file looks like this after start of mongod:

```
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13918 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mo$
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.14
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 92f6668a768ebf294bd4f494c50f48459198e6a3
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-06-28T13:12:41.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127$
2017-06-28T13:12:41.643+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wi$
2017-06-28T13:12:41.643+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=2$
2017-06-28T13:12:42.482+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-06-28T13:12:42.483+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is$
2017-06-28T13:12:42.483+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-06-28T13:12:42.483+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-06-28T13:12:42.483+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is $
2017-06-28T13:12:42.483+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-06-28T13:12:42.483+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-06-28T13:12:42.491+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with direct$
2017-06-28T13:12:42.491+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-06-28T13:12:42.491+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
```

My config files looks like this:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bind

Ip: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#repli

cation:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

I have for example tried this without luck:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DB');
```

The big question is how I should connect to the mongodb database that we can see are running as it should, as we can see in the logs. Do I have to configure nginx to get this to work or do I have the wrong url?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DB');` should work just fine. are you sure you `DB` exists? if so please check the users who can access the DB. regarding to the "big question", so no you do not have to have nginx, mongodb connect to the nodejs. In order to connect the mongo you can use the command "mongo"

Comment: It seems like its actully working, atleast when I made some tests with routes I wont use in production. Hopefully the routes I want to use do not return 404 no more :)

Comment: @HatzavW, you are correct. Kindly, check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33412570/8119511