# How to configure Mongo replicaSet behind reverse proxy

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I've got a replicaSet with three nodes. I'm using a connections string of the following format to connect to the replicaSet:

```
mongodb://user:pass@host_ip_1:port,host_ip_2:port,host_ip_3:port/database?authSource=admin&replicaSet=name_of_replica&readPreference=secondaryPreferred
```

where `host_ip_1`, `host_ip_2`, `host_ip_3` are IP addresses (e.g., `10.234.3.45`, 46, 47)

I want to create a domain which would hide all these IP addresses and allow me to use the connection string as follows:

```
mongodb://user:pass@mongo_domain:port/database?...
```

But I also what such options like `readPreference=secondaryPreferred` to be still working.

How can I do this?

Comment: I understand that, for example NGINX, should be configured somehow. But how?

Comment: it seems this was already answered here (the stream module support raw tcp ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853755/how-to-setup-mongodb-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy

Comment: I saw it. It seems it's not what I need, bcs it explains how to configure NGINX for a single server, not for the replica. To be honest, I'm not sure if this is possible.

The difference is that in my case I want to hide multiple endpoints behind one. And I want still be able to write to one server, but read from another (from replica)